# placing numbers into bins with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I am binning an array into a set of bins using `np.digitize`:

```
data = np.array([1,5,6,15,25,60])
bins = np.array([ 5, 10, 20, 50])
result = np.digitize(data, bins)
# this fails
print bins[result]
```

I want the data to be placed into bins with the interpretation that each value in the bin is interpreted as "less than or equal to" except last bin, which all other values fit into. Is there a function that does this? in this case it would be: "x <= 5, 5 < x <= 10, 10 < x <= 20, and 20 < x <= 50 including x > 50". What's the concise way to do this in numpy?

Comment: What is the exact result you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `20 < x <= 50 including x > 50` for your last bin you are really saying `x>20`.  You can get `x>20` by dropping your last bin of `50`.  [np.digitize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) takes a parameter `right` which will when `True` allow you to have bin behaviour like `10 < x <= 20` rather than the default `10 <= x < 20`

```
>>> data = np.array([1,5,6,15,25,60])
>>> bins = np.array([ 5, 10, 20])
>>> np.digitize(data, bins, right=True)
array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3])
>>>
```

your code `bins[result]` fails because though `bins` is defined with 3 values there are actually 4 intervals `(x<=5, 5<x<=10, 10<x<=20, 20<x)`.  So for example 65 will be placed in bin with index 3 ie. the 4th interval.  The 4th value of `bins` does not exist, hence your error.